# plotly clashes with dplyr programming?

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly, r-plotly

I am re-writing a function that produces a plot, so that the output is powered by `plotly`.

The original function uses [dplyr programming style](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). It has a data-variable in the function arguments and it **embraces** "the argument by surrounding it in doubled braces, like filter(df, {{ var }})".

So far so good, it works fine to pre-process the data and the result can be used to create the plot. `reprex` below works and produces this silly plot.

```r
foo <- function(data, var) {
  plot_data <- data |> 
    dplyr::summarise(min = min({{ var }}), max = max({{ var }}))
  plot_data
}

foo(mtcars, mpg)
#>    min  max
#> 1 10.4 33.9

plotly::plot_ly(data = foo(mtcars, mpg)) |>
  plotly::add_trace(
    x = ~min,
    y = ~max,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Now, if I want to integrate the plot in the function, I get the error below.

```r
bar <- function(data, var) {
  
  plot_data <- data |> 
    dplyr::summarise(min = min({{ var }}), max = max({{ var }}))
  
  plotly::plot_ly(data = plot_data) |>
    plotly::add_trace(
      x = ~min,
      y = ~max,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers"
    )
  
}

bar(mtcars, mpg)
#> Error in as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE): object 'mpg' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It's like `plotly` does not get along with having a variable `var` that should only be evaluated within the data environment, even though the code never explicitly passes `var` to plotly. `plotly` should only be aware of `plot_data` passed to the data argument, and the expressions `~min` and `~max`, passed to the x and y arguments of the `add_trace` function. But still, it tries to find `mpg` in the function environment.

It seems somewhere in the `plotly` code they call `as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE)`, effectively evaluating all objects in the function environment. But I do not really get why is this and how to circumvent it.

A clear workaround could be to pass the variable name as a character vector and use the .data pronoun for wrangling the data.

```r
bar <- function(data, var) {
  
  plot_data <- data |> 
    dplyr::summarise(min = min(.data[[var]]), max = max(.data[[var]]))
  
  plotly::plot_ly(data = plot_data) |>
    plotly::add_trace(
      x = ~min,
      y = ~max,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers"
    )
  
}

bar(mtcars, "mpg")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

That works, I guess because the character vector can always be successfully evaluated in the function environment. But I would really like to keep the interface as in the first attempt.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: what?, mmm, is it perhaps a version issue?, but I swear update plotly and other packages was the first thing I did ;)

Comment: @AdamQuek Have you tried in fresh R session? Only after restarting I was able to replicate the issue.

Comment: @stefan thanks. yup, able to replicate the issue now. sorry.

Comment: yeap, to double-check I've just created a fresh project in rstudio cloud, installed dplyr and plotly and it reproduces. Here's the link to the project. https://rstudio.cloud/project/4115452

Comment: ahh great, thx. Any ideas much appreciated ...

Comment: ... what's interesting. Adding `library(ggplot2)` makes the code work. (: But don't ask me why ...

Comment: nice catch about loading `ggplot2`. But yeah, that's weird.

Comment: Note that if you use the magrittr pipe in your function instead of the base pipe it will work (even just by aliasing the pipe without loading tidyverse packages or magrittr).  Seems related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315290/r-error-combining-tidy-eval-and-tilde-in-plot-ly) and worth filing a bug report.